# PHP: replace characters and make exceptions (preg_replace)

Tags: php, preg-replace, uppercase, lowercase

How do I:

- replace characters in a word using `preg_replace()` but make
  an exception if  they are part of a
  certain word.
- replace an uppercase character with an
  uppercase replacement even if the
  replacement is lowercase and vice
  versa.

example:

```
$string = 'Newton, Einstein and Edison. end';  
echo preg_replace('/n/i', '<b>n</b>', $string);
```

from: **n**ewto**n**, Ei**n**stei**n** a**n**d Ediso**n**. e**n**d
to:   **N**ewto**n**, Ei**n**stei**n** a**n**d Ediso**n**. end

In this case I want all the `n` letters to be replaced unless they are part of the word `end` And `Newton` should not change to `newton`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/((?<!\be)n|n(?!d\b))/i', '<b>\1</b>', $string);
```

It matches any letter 'n' that is either not preceded by [word boundary + e] or not followed by [d + word boundary].

The general case: `/((?<!\b$PREFIX)$LETTER|$LETTER(?!$SUFFIX\b))/i'`

Comment: I would do the look-behind after matching the letter: `/$LETTER(?<!\b$PREFIX$LETTER)(?!$SUFFIX\b)/i`